# Set allowsInlineMediaPlayback for WebView in NativeScript

Tags: ios, webview, nativescript

Where do I set the property "allowsInlineMediaPlayback" in NativeScript for a WebView?

**NativeScript code**

```
var webView = page.getViewById("webview");
webView.on(webViewModule.WebView.loadFinishedEvent, function () {});

if (page.ios){
    webView.ios.scrollView.bounces = false;
    webView.ios.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
    webView.ios.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
    webView.ios.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
    webView.ios.opaque = false;
    webView.ios.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
    webView.ios.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;
}
webView.src = "xx";
```

**Working exemple in Xcode:**

```
func loadWebSite() {
    let theConfiguration:WKWebViewConfiguration? = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let thisPref:WKPreferences = WKPreferences()
    theConfiguration!.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    theConfiguration!.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false

    self.wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: self.getFrame(), configuration: theConfiguration!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem is posted at [github](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5726#issuecomment-383860590)